# Is there a way to convert OpenStreetMap Augmented Diffs (adiff) files into traditional GIS data?

Tags: openstreetamp, adiff

I am looking for a way to convert/import [OpenStreetMap Augmented Diffs files (*adiff*)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Augmented_Diffs) in/into "traditional" GIS data. I don't have enough technical skills to import the XML data into PostgreSQL and then convert them into PostGIS. If anyone knows a non too technical way to achieve the conversion I would like to try it.

The objective is to render it in QGIS (and be able to use the Temporal Controler in addition to other reasons). Tags could' be stored in *hstore* since QGIS manages them.

For information, a *adiff* can be loaded in QGIS (I think with the [*OSM OGR driver*](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html)) and it works partially after exporting layers into Geopackage. From what I am able to understand, the *OGR driver* could be able to load everything but the problem is with OSM ids which are used as unique ids and it is a problem since 2 versions of each objects exists in the file.